# Take snapshot from running pipeline in gstreamer with iOS

Tags: ios, swift2, gstreamer

I'm trying to create a snapshot from a running pipeline in iOS. I use a button to take the snapshot.

I have the following pipeline

```
udpsrc auto-multicast=true address=224.1.1.1 port=5004"
+ " ! application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z0JAH6aAQAYZAA\\,aM4wpIAA\", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)19088743, timestamp-offset=(uint)0, seqnum-offset=(uint)0"
+ " ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=400"
+ " ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert"
+ " ! tee name=snapshot snapshot. ! queue ! valve name=snap drop=true ! jpegenc ! filesink name=filepath location=screenshot.jpg async=false snapshot. ! queue"
+ " ! autovideosink
```

So I use the following code in my button to handle the valve:

```
GstElement *element = gst_bin_get_by_name (GST_BIN (pipeline), "snap");
if (strcmp("drop", "drop") == 0)
{
    gboolean prop_val = FALSE;

    // if the property value is true, then send an EOS.
    if ( strcmp("false", "true") == 0 )
    {
        gst_element_send_event(element, gst_event_new_eos());
        prop_val = TRUE;
    } else {
        prop_val = FALSE;
    }

    g_object_set (element, "drop", prop_val, NULL);
}
```

But with this code I can only take one screenshot. And I can't set the filename of the image.

How can I save the screenshot without blocking the stream and save the image in the documents folder with a custom name every time the button is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

After a long search and struggle I found a solution so I will answer my question myself.

I've removed the tee from my pipeline and use the last sample of the video buffer now.

My pipeline:

```
udpsrc auto-multicast=true address=224.1.1.1 port=5004"
+ " ! application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z0JAH6aAQAYZAA\\,aM4wpIAA\", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)19088743, timestamp-offset=(uint)0, seqnum-offset=(uint)0"
+ " ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=400"
+ " ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert"
+ " ! autovideosink
```

This is my Objective-C code:

```
-(UIImage*) takeSnapshot
{
    GstSample *videobuffer = NULL;
    GstCaps *caps;
    gint width, height;
    GstMapInfo map;

    g_object_get(G_OBJECT(video_sink), "last-sample", &videobuffer, NULL);

    if (videobuffer)
    {
        caps = gst_sample_get_caps(videobuffer);

        if (!caps) {
            return NULL;
        }

        GstStructure *s = gst_caps_get_structure(caps, 0);
        /* we need to get the final caps on the buffer to get the size */
        gboolean res;
        res = gst_structure_get_int (s, "width", &width);
        res |= gst_structure_get_int (s, "height", &height);
        if (!res) {
            return NULL;
        }

        GstBuffer *snapbuffer = gst_sample_get_buffer(videobuffer);
        if (snapbuffer && gst_buffer_map (snapbuffer, &map, GST_MAP_READ))
        {
            CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL,
                                                                  map.data,
                                                                  height * width * 4,
                                                                  NULL);

            CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
            CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
            CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

            CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width,
                                            height,
                                            8,
                                            4 * 8,
                                            width * 4,
                                            colorSpaceRef,
                                            bitmapInfo,
                                            provider,
                                            NULL,
                                            NO,
                                            renderingIntent);

            UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
            CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
            CGImageRelease(imageRef);

            return uiImage;
        }

        return NULL;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```